# AngularJS getting undefined from $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm currently working on a little AngularJS project.

I got this code in my Service.

```
    testApp.service('testService',['databaseService', 'loggedService', '$http', function(databaseService, loggedService, $http){

    this.getDetails= function(name){

        $http({
            method : "GET",
            url : "url"       
        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
           return response.data;
        }, function myError(response) {
            $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
        });

    };

}]);
```

I'm calling the method from my service in a controller:

```
testApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$http', 'testService', function($scope, $http, testService){

    $scope.details;

    $scope.loadDetails= function(val){
        $scope.details= testService.getDetails(val);
        console.log($scope.details);
        console.log(val);
    };

}]);
```

The $scope.loadDetails is being called in my view when a user is typing something in a search field. So it has to auto-update the dropdown.

The response.data in the service returns an array. 
But the $scope.details in the controller stays undefined. Anyone knows how to return the response.data from the service to the controller?

I already tried returning the response.data outside the $http, but i keep getting undefined in the controller.

Comment: have you injected the service in the controller??

Comment: can you add the dependency list for the service and controller, I suspect you didn't inject something\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The communication via $http is asynchronous and works through promises.
The call to `$http` returns a promise and the `.then` call returns a promise as well.
If you add `return response.data` there the resulting promise will be resolved with the array of your data. You need to `return` the promise from the `getDetails` function as well, therefore add `return $http(...`.

Now, in your controller, when you call `testService.getDetails()` you will get the promise. It is not the result itself though, so there's no point in assigning the returned value to scope. Instead, you need to call another `.then` on that promise with a callback function that will assign the value to the `$scope`.

In service:

```
this.getDetails= function(name){

    return $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "url"       
    }).then(function (response) {
       return response.data;
    });

};
```

In controller:

```
$scope.loadDetails= function(val) {
    testService.getDetails(val).then(function(data) {
        $scope.details = data;
    });        
};
```

Comment: It finally worked! Thank you very much for the good explanation.

Comment: Saved me today. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're handling the promises the wrong way. This line:

`$scope.details = detailsService.getDetails(val);` assigns the return value of `detailsService.getDetails` to `$scope.details`. Currently the `detailsService.getDetails` doesn't return anything and so you get `undefined`. If you must handle the response in the service, then you can do something like:

```
return $http({
  method : "GET",
  url : "url"      
})`
```

You're returning the `$http` promise.

Comment: If i understand this correctly, even though i use return response.data in the service it still returns a promes?

Comment: Right now you're not returning the promise. The http is asynchronous and your response.data  gets returned late. At that time the getDetails function has returned undefined already